# Angular material discrete mode UI Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

am using angular material 1.x version's md-slider discrete mode.The problem is slider binds ng-model in the button when I drop it to the respective point like 1 or 2 or 3.This issue only in ios web view mode, not in safari, chrome, firefox, ie. so I want to show the value only in drag and not in drop.And below is my HTML code.

```
<md-slider-container>
    <md-slider id="detect" flexmin="0" md-discrete ng-model="setVal.model.SliderValue" step="1" min="-3" max="3" aria-label="blue" class="md-primary">
    </md-slider>
</md-slider-container>
```